# How to use material design iconic font as a marker for <li> element?

Tags: html-lists, marker

Is there possible way to use icons from http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-iconic-font/icons.html as a markers for

elements?

Answer (score 1):

use :before selector with Unicode the icon

```
li:before {    
font-family: 'Material-Design-Iconic-Font';
content: '\f34e';
margin:0 15px 0 -15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Soufiane_Abid/8fwyfdyk/

or

```
<div class="list-group">
<a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home zmdi-hc-fw"> 
</i> Home</a>
<a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-inbox zmdi-hc-fw">
</i> Inbox</a>
<a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star zmdi-hc-fw">
</i> Starred</a>
<a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email-open zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Drafts</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the class for icon  example google icon

```
<i class="zmdi zmdi-google"></i>
```

before that you most be included in HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
```

Comment: thanks, but how to make <i class="zmdi zmdi-google"></i> become a marker? How to connect it with <li> element?